# create table contain cube and square of numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i just started to learn javascript few days ago and i want to create a table listing the numbers 1 to 20 together with their squares and cubes but i fail to create it. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <table id="mytable"></table>

    <script>
        var number = new Array(20);
        for(var i =0; i<number.length; i++)
        {
            number[i] = i+1;
        }
        var table = document.getElementById("mytable");

        var caption = table.createCaption();
        caption.appendChild(document.createTextNode("cube and square"));

        var thead = table.createTHead();
        var tbody = table.createTBody();
        var thr = thead.insertRow(-1);

        var thr_d0 = thr.insertCell(-1);
        thr_d0.appendChild(document.createTextNode("num"));
        var thr_d1 = thr.insertCell(-1);
        thr_d1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("square"));
        var thr_d2 = thr.insertCell(-1);
        thr_d2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("cube"));

        var cube = new Array();
        var square = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            cube[i] = Math.pow(number[i],3);
            square[i] = Math.pow(number[i],2);
            var tbr = tbody.insertRow(-1);
            var tbr_d0 = tbr.insertCell(-1);
            tbr_d0.appendChild(document.createTextNode(square[i]));
            var tbr_d1 = tbr.insertCell(-1);
            tbr_d1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cube[i]);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;    
just this...

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery? If so, it's [really easy](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/EL95t/1/).

Comment: didnt learn jQuery.  just start to learn js and wan practice it

Comment: This line is the unexpected semi-colon: `tbr_d1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cube[i]);`  It's because you're missing a `)`

Comment: OMG!!! i was like spending an hr plus on this and i didnt notice it...thx so much

Comment: Personally, I found it easier to learn jQuery first and then backtrack and learn javascript. You can develop a better understanding of the web with jQuery imo

Comment: Looks like you're listing the squares and cubes, but you also wanted the original numbers.  Try also adding this after the line with `insertRow` in your loop:
`tbr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(number[i]));`

Comment: ya i accidentally delete that line when i editing. btw thx for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using an array makes the problem overly complicated. Instead, just use a `for` loop and insert the values using basic arithmetic:

```
<table id="myTable"></table>

<script>
    //assign the table to a variable
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    //title the different columns with number, square, and cube
    var head = table.insertRow(0);
        head.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = "number";
        head.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = "square";
        head.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = "cube";
    //run a for loop to put the squares and cubes of 1 to 20
    for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++){
        var holder = table.insertRow(-1);
        holder.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = i;
        holder.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = (i*i);
        holder.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = (i*i*i);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertRow' of null 3.html:25
(anonymous function)

Comment: @user3450475 Which browser are you using?

Comment: @user3450475 Look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp). Also, what does line 25 refer to in your file?

Comment: line 25 refer to this >>     var head = table.insertRow(0);

Comment: @user3450475 Oh, I changed the id of the table to `myTable`. You weren't using camelCase

Comment: ok gt it. thx for this short code. I just follow what I've learn in class and it's make it so long ==

Comment: @user3450475 You'll get better with time =) I find the key to making clear and concise code it to think the problem through first, take note of wherever you need to repeat processes, and then try writing the solution.